# Bloquear Scroll do Rato

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como bloquear o *scroll whell* do mouse em uma `div` utilizando JavaScript ou jQuery?

Comment: Bloquear o `scroll` da roda do rato para que apenas o `scroll` clicando e arrastando a `scrollbar` funcione, é isso?

Comment: Bloquear o  `scroll` da roda do  rato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer isso da seguinte maneira com Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById('meuID').onwheel = function(){ return false; }
```

```css
body {height:1000px;}
#meuID {
    width:150px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="meuID">
    <div style="height:1200px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1, porém recomendo utilizar overflow-y com valor "auto" ao invés de "scroll".

Comment: Verdade @DorivalZanetto! eu é que construí esse exemplo de empreitada e o `scroll` foi o valor que foi na 'onda' xD